# FORM C#: COMO NÃO DEIXA CAMPO TEXT BOX COM VALOR DE VARIÁVEL DOUBLE EM BRACO

Tags: c#

**Boa tarde, estou realizado um programa básico para aperfeiçoar na programação mas estou tendo um erro aqui, já tentei vários jeitos e não consigo. É um programa de calculo de IMC EM Windows Form, mas na hora que o programa roda aparece o campo de Altura e Peso e quando o usuário fosse inserir os dados não queria que os dois campos ficassem em branco pois me parece que o não tem como fazer pq o valor é double e so tem como verificar string pois é textbox, quando aperto no botão para calcula com os campo vazio ele encerra no altura = convert.todouble(txtaltura.text);. o inicio do cogido está assim: alguém me ajuda?
            double Altura, Peso, imc;

```
        Altura = Convert.ToDouble(txtAltura.Text);
        Peso = Convert.ToDouble(txtPeso.Text);
        if (txtAltura == null && txtPeso == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("DIGITE UM VALOR");

        }
        else
        {
            Altura = Convert.ToDouble(txtAltura.Text);
            Peso = Convert.ToDouble(txtPeso.Text);
            imc = Peso / (Altura * Altura);**
```

Comment: por favor, letras maiusculas na internet significa que está gritando, por favor, "baixo-o-tom-de-voz" no titulo!

Comment: Ok, foi mal é porque eu sou novo aqui no site e não deduzir isso. Valeeu!

Answer (score 4):

Há vários problemas de lógica em seu algoritmo.

1. Você está tentando converter os valores antes mesmo de valida-los.
2. Você está convertendo os valores dos campos de uma forma que não é segura.
3. Está repetindo operações, convertendo os valores novamente.

O que sugiro à você.

Utilize a função `string.IsNullOrEmpty` para validar se seu campo tem ou não valor.
Exemplo:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAltura.Text))
{
   //Algum código aqui
}
```

Utilize a função `double.TryParse` para tentar fazer parse do valor do campo para um valor do tipo `double`.
Exemplo:

```
double.TryParse(txtAltura.Text, out double altura)
```

Por fim, deixo aqui como deveria ser feito essa implementação na minha visão:

```
//Aqui valida se os campos tem valor
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAltura.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPeso.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("DIGITE UM VALOR");
}
else
{
    //Aqui tenta fazer parse do valor do campo altura
    if (!double.TryParse(txtAltura.Text, out double altura))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ALTURA INVÁLIDA");
    }
    else
    {
        //Aqui tenta fazer parse do valor do campo altura
        if (!double.TryParse(txtPeso.Text, out double peso))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PESO INVÁLIDO");
        }
        else
        {
            //Se deu tudo certo, calcula o imc
            var imc = peso / (altura * altura);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeeu cara, era isso mesmo, me desculpa é porque eu sou novo na área, por isso tinha muitos erros kkk como se diz errando que se aprende né ? mas muito obrigado mesmo pela atenção.